# How to render SVG files in Cocos Creator?

Tags: svg, cocoscreator

Does Cocos Creator currently support SVG format files? If so, how can I render them in a scene? If not, is there an extension of some sort which would allow that?

Comment: please give an similiar example of svg file, to know how complex it is, how can we help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option natively. There's a third party tool (https://github.com/stefandee/raphael-example) that provides SVG file support but it's incomplete (doesn't work with certain SVG files) and supports only the older Cocos Creator versions.

Source: https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/does-cocos-creator-support-svg-format-files/50967/2?u=quickz